# SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search - result of file share

Tags: search, permissions, search-results, enterprise-search

In case when SharePoint content access account has full permissions to all files share, if user who has permissions to only one folder will be able to see rest of folders and will have access to it?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the results will be security trimmed and you only see what you would see when you directly access a fileshare.

Comment: BUT... your crawl account should be configured for READ, not full access, particularly for SharePoint Content Sources.

Comment: That answer isn't true necessarily. From what I am seeing in my search results, you can still see files on a file server but get "Page Not Found" when trying to access them without permissions on the file share folder..Perhaps I am missing some configuration

Comment: @John M - then something is wrong, that is not the standard behaviour. Open a new question.